# How to stop condtions if the first one is met?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following OR conditions in a procedure:

```
    WHERE table1.url LIKE '%_50%' OR table1.url LIKE '%_60%' OR table1.url LIKE '%_70%'
```

This where clause brings all urls that contain these values (_50, _60, _70) for each set of data that is uniquely identified by a ProductID. Instead, I would like to get only a single record for each Product that meets a single condition of those values. What is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. You want a single record, or an entire result set? Your comment on the answer by @Giorgos Bestos implies (to me) that you have some column to partition by, or at least some other criteria you haven't shared with us.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `ORDER BY` clause, like:

```
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN table1.url LIKE '%_50%' THEN 1
            WHEN table1.url LIKE '%_60%' THEN 2
            WHEN table1.url LIKE '%_70%' THEN 3
         END
```

Using `TOP 1` in the `SELECT` clause will get you the record required.

**Edit:**

To get one record for each partition you can use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE 
                                           WHEN table1.url LIKE '%_50%' THEN 1
                                           WHEN table1.url LIKE '%_60%' THEN 2
                                           WHEN table1.url LIKE '%_70%' THEN 3
                                         END
                            ORDER BY table1.url) AS rn
FROM table1
WHERE table1.url LIKE '%_50%' OR 
      table1.url LIKE '%_60%' OR 
      table1.url LIKE '%_70%' ) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: The only challenge I see with this approach, is that using TOP 1 will limit the select statement itself, which is not desired. The select statement will have to return multiple records where each one of them will have either a url _50, _60, or _70

Comment: @usefulBee I thought you wanted a *single* record returned. Is this not the case?

Comment: Sorry about that, my intention was one record of each single set of data.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, I would suggest Partitioning by ProductID and ordering by the `CASE` statement, otherwise this query will only return records for `table1.url LIKE '%_50%`. +1 however, as I had the same solution in mind.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong about what is returned, but the suggestion still stands as this answer, as written, gives the wrong result set unless I misunderstand the question.